# Android LinearLayout background image from gallery is not working in some device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

I am setting a background image to linearlayout from gallery,its working fine unless the size of the image is too large,I have implemented the exception handling and if there is any exception then I am setting a default background from resource,but still my app is crashing.here is my code...

```
  public static void setBackgroundImage(Context context,
        LinearLayout linearLayout, Uri uri) {

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context
                .getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
                bitmap);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            setImageForJellyBeanOrLater(linearLayout, drawable);
        } else {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_bg_image);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private static void setImageForJellyBeanOrLater(LinearLayout linearLayout,
        Drawable drawable) {
    linearLayout.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the image u select from gallery should be cropped.

try the below code,It works for me .

get the size of layout :

```
    final int width = frm_layout.getWidth();
    final int height = frm_layout.getHeight();
```

And then compress using below,

```
    thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath));
    thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, width, height ,true);
```

Comment: I have modified the code,it is class name ,the code was from my project it had a different need